# Inspecting “tidynetwork” element in chrome to find its origin on my laptop

Tags: malware, virus, chrome

Anyone heard of the "TidyNetwork" virus/malware? Is it possible to determine the origin of the ad that is created on web pages by Tidy by inspecting the element using developer tools? I am using chrome.

or, of anyone knows of it, do you know to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

I mean, I don't want to be a jerk here but you leave me no [choice](https://www.google.com/search?q=TidyNetwork&aq=f&oq=TidyNetwork).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this analysis](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan%3AWin32%2FPaidemet.A&ThreatID=-2147307663) of *TidyNetwork* (or *Win32/Paidemet.A* how Microsoft and some other Antivirus software vendors decided to name this adware trojan), it is capable of updating its database with new advertising sources, so that identification of the origin or adverts that you're interested in might not be as easy as simply inspecting their source and target locations. Some companies do however track [link associations](http://com.tidynetwork.qirina.com/) and collate data that identifies network neighborhoods, and that can be used to determine to some degree of certainty, if an advert's source/target location is a part of the same *TidyNetwork* scheme. However, even this (or other similar) list is a subject to change.

As for removal, it isn't a particularly pesky visitor, and you shouldn't have problems neither detecting it, nor later removing it with antivirus tools from pretty much any major vendor. Just make sure you don't fall for another scheme by following instructions on some suspicious looking page, luring new victims into downloading and running a *too convenient to be true, one click solves it all*  .exe file, and end up installing a new bunch of viruses instead. If you're not sure, go for solutions from [trusted vendors](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/antivirus-partners/windows-7.aspx).